# SQL Server : multiple counts with joins

Tags: sql-server, database, count

I am writing a query that lists the number of customers served by particular employees in a banking scenario.

The tables are designed like this:

[Table Design](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IKCgb.png)

The following queries produce the results I need singularly:

```
SELECT 
    EMPID, COUNT(EMPID) AS 'Customers Served' 
FROM 
    Financial.AccountOperations 
GROUP BY 
    EMPID;

SELECT 
    EMPID, COUNT(EMPID) AS 'Customers Served' 
FROM 
    Financial.LoanOperations
GROUP BY 
    EMPID;
```

[Query Results](https://i.stack.imgur.com/w5tl3.png)

I am trying to combine the queries into one. I have tried using `UNION`, `INTERSECT`, `JOIN`, and subqueries without any success.

Can anyone please help?

Desired output would look like:

```
 EMPID         Customers Served  
   2                2  
   3                3  
   4               17  
   5               16  
   7                2  
   8                4  
   9                8  
  10                5  
  12                1  
  15                1
```

Comment: what do you mean by `combine`? Do you want to add COUNTs for matching employees? or Do you want to merge outputs?

Comment: Please provide an example of the desired output.

Comment: Added desired output, thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think @Hogan has it - just take it one more step:

```
SELECT EMPID, Sum([Customers Served]) AS NumServed FROM
(SELECT EMPID,COUNT(EMPID) AS 'Customers Served' 
FROM Financial.AccountOperations
GROUP BY EMPID
UNION
SELECT EMPID,COUNT(EMPID) AS 'Customers Served'
FROM Financial.LoanOperations 
GROUP BY EMPID)
GROUP BY EMPID
```

Comment: You are a genius. This worked perfectly. Thank you every so much!

Comment: thanks dbmitch -- I had to go to a meeting so I didn't see the part about needing a sum.  you should get the upvote :D

Answer (score 2):

Did you try this:

```
SELECT EMPID,COUNT(EMPID) AS 'Customers Served' 
FROM Financial.AccountOperations
GROUP BY EMPID

UNION

SELECT EMPID,COUNT(EMPID) AS 'Customers Served'
FROM Financial.LoanOperations 
GROUP BY EMPID;
```

I think I would do this

```
SELECT 'Account' AS Source, EMPID,COUNT(EMPID) AS 'Customers Served' 
FROM Financial.AccountOperations
GROUP BY EMPID

UNION ALL

SELECT 'Loan' AS Source, EMPID,COUNT(EMPID) AS 'Customers Served'
FROM Financial.LoanOperations 
GROUP BY EMPID;
```

Comment: Hey! Thanks for responding. I have yes, however, the results come back with multiple rows for empids that exist in both tables when I need it to be in one row. For example, EMPID 4 has served 17 customers but it comes back in two rows stating 9 and 8 separaerly